# Can use Berkeley DB in mobile phone

Tags: python, database, mobile, windows-mobile, berkeley-db

Can i use `Berkeley DB`  python classes in mobile phone directly , i mean Do DB python classes and methods are ready to be used in any common mobile phone like `Nokia`,`Samsong (windows mobile)`..etc.

If a phone system supports python language, does that mean that it is easy and straightforward to use Berkeley DB on it...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Berkeley DB is a library that needs to be available. What you *may* have is Python bindings to Berkeley DB. If the library is not present, having Python will not help.

Look for SQLite, which may be present (it is for iPhone) as it has SQL support and its library size is smaller than Berkeley DB, which makes it better suited for mobile OSes.